# Rounded Corners in Google Pie Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, donut-chart

Is it possible to make the edges of one dataset round in Google Charts (Pie Chart)?

I want something similar to this:

[image]

Now I know one can achieve this with chart.js or mostly other chart plugins. But I'm looking for the solution within the Google Charts plugin. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.charts.load('visualization', '1');

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Content', 'Size'],
    ['Green', 70],
    ['Grey', 30]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    title: "",
    pieHole: 0.8,
    pieSliceBorderColor: "none",
    colors: ['#71B55D', '#eaeaea'],
    chartArea: {
     width: '85%',
     height: '85%'
    },
    legend: {
      position: "none"
    },
    pieSliceText: "none",
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "none"
    }
  };

  var donutChart = new google.visualization
   .PieChart(document.getElementById('donut-chart'));

  donutChart.draw(data, options);
}
```

JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/jv25s9aL/4/

Comment: I don't think thats possible in google charts. I checked out the google charts visualization options from [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) but can't find an option for this

Comment: it's not possible with standard config options, but you can manually change the svg on the chart's `'ready'` event...

Comment: Thank you MuhammadOsama and WhiteHat, appreciate the response.